# Memory leak after time-out?

Tags: arangodb

in ArangoDB 2.4.0 I observe the following. When executing a query which runs in a time out, there seems to be a memory leak. Description:

1. I execute a query which is lasting longer than allowed by the setting request-timeout = 3600 (e.g. in arangosh config).
2. arandod starts working, consumes CPU and RAM
3. After the given time (here: 3600 seconds) the query throws an 
       exception (`2001 - could not connect to server`) which by the way 
       at first was a bit confusing, as in my case its not a connect error, 
       it's a timeout error).
4. arangodb stops using CPU, but does not free the RAM which was used.
5. Up to now, even while further use, the RAM never went down again.
       I even can unload all collections, so the RAM must be blocked 
       from somewhat else.

As long as I run queries which can be finished before the timeout arrives, run perfectly.

Is it possible that in such scenario there is a memory leak? Or do I manually have to start some kind of garbage collector or to do something else?

Comment: Just as add-on: Currently again a situation like this: (A) no more external arango request is running (B) arangod has 0% CPU (C) all collections are unloaded from memory (D) arangod still uses qw GB of RAM........ After starting the shutdown (with Ctrl-C) arangodb does some work, works a couple of minutes thereby reducing memory, and THEN re-allocating all memory again and again: even more then ever used before ..... in consequence I have to kill the process.

Comment: Surprisingly, now the same happens after restart: the server works since a few minutes, thereby taking all RAM (and even more) ....

Comment: .... there is no open shell. After closing the browser interface, also arangodb stops working. After re-opening the browser interface I see that 2 collections used half an hour before are "automaticalle" loaded. After unloading them manualle, RAM usage is back at 550K. After another arangod restart everything seems to be back in normality.

Answer (score 1):

OK, in the meanwhile I at least have some (partial?) answers:

1. In some of those "error scenarios", also new Skiplist indexes where
   created. This seems to be a tasks which runs much longer than thought, 
   and also takes up very much of additional RAM space.
   Now, when killing the server and restarting it again, the server again 
   wants to do the initial index building, so the whole collection, 
   the index space, the new index and a large amount of temporary RAM 
   are needed.
2. the web interface seems to be single-threaded, even arangosh commands are 
   blocked in the meanwhile. So, if you click to additional buttons or type 
   a command which e.g. also needs to load additional collections while 
   executing, the simply will be delayed ... and maybe executed at a point
   of time where you do not expect them to run any more. So I declare them
   as beginner pitfalls of mine :-)

Comment: After some more days of work with arangodb, I very often observe similar problems: If you fire a query which (due to any reasons) take too long or are going to get out of RAM and thus, enforce you to interrupt the system, you only have one chance: kill the server. In this case the next server start might be self-deployed for a longer time. Unfortunately up to now there is no way to a) have an overview of currently running arango jobs (e.g. in the dashboard) and b) to stop/kill/abort dedicatedly one of them.